# Using window.Touch to find out if current device is a mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile

Is it okay to do the following to determine if you are on mobile device?

```
if(window.Touch != undefined) 
{
   //redirect to my mobile site
}
```

I would like to do a small check to see if its a mobile device. I don't want to import [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library just for this simple check.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do and so far it has worked pretty well:

```
var HAS_TOUCH = ('ontouchstart' in window);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using:

```
if(window.MSPointerEvent){
    //you are on IE10
}else if(window.PointerEvent){
    //you are on IE11
}else if(window.TouchEvent){
    //android and safari
}else{
    //don't have touch events
}
```

I tested this on Android 2.3 and 4.4.2 and on iOS 7.1. For the IE I used what [Microsoft recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn304886(v=vs.85).aspx)

Using `TouchEvent` only works if you are on a touch device; that doesn't mean a mobile device. For that use a regular expression on the `userAgent`:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){
    //you are on Android or iPhone
}
```

But there are a lot of other cases to treat, for example, Windows Phone and BlackBerry, so I recommend using the [detect mobile API](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com).

Answer (score 0):

Okay found something after extensive search.  window.touch [doesn't work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript/3996900#3996900)   at least that is what someone has said. I can't confirm since I don't have a mobile device that runs Android