# Jquery - best way to detect mobile browser? (mousedown/touchmove)

Tags: jquery, mobile, mousedown, touchmove

I have some Jquery scroller.

For desktop browsers I use this construction:

```
holder.bind('mousedown.rotate', function(e){
    //some actions  
    doc.bind('mousemove.dragrotate', function(e){
        //some actions          
    });
    doc.bind('mouseup.dragrotate', function(){
        //some actions  
        doc.unbind('.dragrotate');
    });
});
```

for mobile browsers it works in this way:

```
holder.bind('touchmove', function(jQueryEvent) {
//some actions
});
```

what is the best way to determine mobile borwsers?
is there a way to use same function for all platforms?

thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` to check what browser the user is using... the following code would be a good starting point.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) {
    // Mobile browser specific code here
}
```

[Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) has a JS file you can use if you want to get more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

[Detecting touch screen devices with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript/6447935#6447935)