# How can I detect the existence of a mouse in a web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

On a web site I'm building, I've got a set of navigation buttons that needs to be large to look nice and be easily clickable, but needs to be small when the user isn't navigating.  So in my UI, I shrink the buttons down to a thumbnail, and on mouse hover I animate it to full size.  This works well.

But on tablets, there's no mouse, and no mouse hover, and so I need another mechanism for letting users navigate.  I was thinking of letting the user tap on the thumbnail, then expanding the full nav button bar, and then the user can tap to navigate.

The question is: how can I tell if the user is browsing with no mouse?  I guess I could browser detect, but this seems really flaky.

Alternatively, can someone point me to a better UI design pattern for this situation?

Comment: Not really useful now but there is talk of a media query that will detect this which is pretty cool - http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/07/w3c-looking-to-improve-responsive-design-with-new-media-queries/

Comment: Several plausible answers here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript

Comment: @SpaceBeers: That's interesting.  Will file it away for when browsers start supporting it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript  (it's the converse)

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - It's on my radar but I think we might be waiting a while...

Comment: @PhilipK: Will read through that page and see what I can find.  Thanks.

Comment: @Faust: Thanks, will read and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to detect the browser agent.

But you may also register listeners for `touchstart/touchmove/touchend` events which are triggered only on touch devices.

BTW there is a new [CSS media queries in level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries4/#pointer).

Perhaps the most interesting for you would be the "pointer", for which the user agent is expected to return “none | coarse | fine.” According to the the spec, “typical examples of a ‘fine’ pointing system are a mouse, a track-pad or a stylus-based touch screen. Finger-based touch screens would qualify as ‘coarse.’”

Answer (score 0):

create a custom click event, bind it with a function, then finally dispatch the created click event to the document. If the function successfully managed to trigger, then the user has a mouse otherwise it could be any mouseless device

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEvent(ev)
{
    var d=document;
    var isTrue=false;
    var fn=function()
    {
        isTrue=true;
    }
    d.body.onclick=fn;
    var e;
    if(d.createEvent)
    {
        e=d.createEvent('Event');
        e.initEvent(ev,false,false);
        d.body.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
    else if(d.createEventObject)
    {
        e=d.createEventObject(window.event);
        d.body.fireEvent('on'+ev,e);
    }
    return isTrue;
}

//run the code
var isMouse=isEvent('click');
if(isMouse)
{
    alert('user has a mouse');
}
```

Make sure to run only when the loading of the body started! 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8yYRK/)