# Designing CSS Menus cross compatible with iPad

Tags: css, ipad, menu, cross-browser

I built a website that works great on Firefox, IE, and Chrome.  Client goes to a tradeshow and realizes the website menu went bonkers in their iPad.
[broken menu http://www.glassdoctordenvermetro.com/wp-content/themes/GDDenverTheme/images/photo.JPG](http://www.glassdoctordenvermetro.com/wp-content/themes/GDDenverTheme/images/photo.JPG)

I tried a website that lets you preview your design by simulating it in case you don't have an iPad (like me).  But the problem is it looks fine:
http://ipadpreview.com/previewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fglassdoctordenvermetro.com%2F

What would suggest I do to figure this out?  Is it a problem with the font being different on every browser perhaps?  The width of the tab changes based on the menu font and wording but again, it looks fine on all other browsers I tested.

Thank you

Comment: If you happen to be on a Mac there's a nice iPad/iPhone simulator available through xcode

Comment: Believe me, I wish I had a Mac.  It would solve 90% of my frustration in life.

Comment: In general, yes, fonts can be entirely different on iOS devices and I'd guess that's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening it an iPad simulator shows that the font is a much wider font and there's also greater letter spacing.  You should specify more options in the `font-family` tag to have another more condensed font that is available on iOS.  You could also bring the font-size down on iOS.  The big issue with the testing site you're using is that it's still outputting HTML, the only trustworthy type of site like that would have to generate a screenshot image to ensure consistency.

Here's some fonts to help: http://iosfonts.com/

And `11px` works with the existing font.

Alternately, removing the uppercase transform makes it fit.

Comment: Does this mean I need to locate a browser detect script to see that it is an ipad, and somehow replace a css portion of the code with an ipad font reference?

Comment: You wouldn't have to for the font-family, but I haven't had any luck with any of them on your site.  In general I think condensed fonts will be a problem on mobile devices due to possible legibility issues.  I'd first suggest trying to get rid of the transform...or a word out of the content which could be done for all environments.  Otherwise if you just need the slight detection for iOS you could start by just using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript and then adjusting the font size or whatever else you need.

Comment: Understood.  Yes, these menus are a lot more "wordy" that most I've worked on.  I put in a suggestion to go title case instead of all caps.  One thing led to another when they wanted a lot of words and caps.  Had to try condensed to make it fit.  I will go with your suggestion!

Comment: You could also use a media query if needed, checking the screen size and the pixel ratio should cover iOS.