# How do i disable onmouse and onmouseout function on touchcreen devices only

Tags: jquery, html, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am creating a responsive shopping site for a clothing brand and have a `onmouseover=""` and     `onmouseout=""` effect on my `<img>` tags to show the front and back of the products, like on http://www.blackmilkclothing.com

But when viewing the site on a touchscreen device the hover effect is obviously set as a click function. which makes it not able to scroll down fluently

How would i disable this effect for touch screen devices only?
Here is my code for the images

```
<div class="product">
   <a href="">
      <img src="pic.jpg"onmouseover="this.src='pic2.jpg'"onmouseout="this.src='pic.jpg'" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Detecting touch screen devices with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript) - how to detect touch screen. 
For your code:

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
    if (is_touch_device) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        elements[i].onmouseover = null;
        elements[i].onmouseout = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot worked great. still having scrolling issues with the site though must be down to something else which i can't figure out

Answer (score 0):

I can only think about http://modernizr.com/ which lets you know if the viewer has a touch-screen or not.

The plugin adds a class to the `<html>` `.touch` and `.no-touch`

Now you could do something like

```
if($('html').hasClass('no-touch')){
   $('img').mouseover(function(){ //change pic 
           }).mouseout(function(){ //change back 
           });
}
```

This will only add the `mouseover` event for devices without touch-screens

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test the User Agent on the load of the page and assign the "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" events dynamically (if the User Agent is not mobile), all using JQuery or Javascript.