# Touchscreen specific stylesheets/commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touchscreen

Is there a way to detect if the user is on a touchscreen device? I want to change some HTML/jquery based on that fact (more specifically, [jquery capSlide](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/23/jcapslide-a-jquery-image-caption-plugin/) to show caption on touchscreen devices while hiding it on desktop). What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: `modernizr` is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner should suffice.

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

Taken from this Stack Overflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447935/1585455

Your conditional should look something like this:

```
if(is_touch_device) { /* your code */ }
```

Comment: Would I put those within my script tag?

Comment: @vytfla Yes. It's JavaScript. I do wonder why you're using inline scripts instead of external scripts though..

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. What is the reason to use external scripts over internal?

Comment: @vytfla The browser has to switch between processors during inline scripting. Basically it's faster to have an external script instead.