# What the difference between tablet and laptop with touch screen?

Tags: javascript, touch, device-detection

Tablets and laptops with touch-screen have "touch" support. So how we can to detect with help of javascript that it's a laptop but not a tablet?

P.S.: I don't need to detect touch device. I need to distinguish laptop with touch screen from a tablet.

Comment: the first hit on google leads to [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript)

Comment: @Jonesy: that thread only deals with detecting touch screens. At Pavel: just wondering why you would want to distinguish between a laptop with touch screen and a tablet? What would be the practical implications?

Answer (score 1):

```
var isLaptopWithTouchScreen;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    isLaptopWithTouchScreen = true;
});
```