# Detect Touch Capabilities When Inside A Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, touch

Can I detect touch capabilities within a browser (JavaScript). Is that a property or should I go for OS property?

I want to be able to switch between a desktop and a touch device using different design elements which feel different and are controlled differently.

[Update]

I also need a way to detect if a computer with touch screen is using a mouse or if it is touched. When i detect one is using touch i would like the software to switch to touch instantly removing details and also exchange the visual components.

One idea is to monitor the mouse movement and see if it is jumping or if it smoothly moving. Any better way? Does something (library) like this exist?

Comment: see http://modernizr.com/

Comment: A short Google search would have taken you to [this SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974827/detecting-touch-screen-devices-with-javascript)

Comment: Nope wont do the trick this is from 2010. Thats like to tackle a Football pro with a ice bear. Today I have a 12" notebook with a 12" ipad. Wont do the trick. I need a good solution.