# ontouchstart exists in window object on non-touch devices

Tags: javascript, html, windows-10

I have an issue when on regular desktop PC without touch screen in any browser either it's Chrome, IE, Edge, or Mozilla I see that **window** object has *ontouchstart* property. This happens only on Windows version 1607 (Anniversary update) and does not happen on any other version of Windows 10.

I'm asking because in my code I used to detect if it's touch screen by line of code below

```
var isTouchScreen = !! ( ('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch || (navigator && navigator.maxTouchPoints));
```

But now in Windows 1607 this variable always returns TRUE even if I work on desktop PC without touch screen and that breaks a lot of logic in my code.

Does anybody know what's wrong with that particular Windows version?

Comment: The test is not reliable, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart#Browser_compatibility A good post about the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447935/1169519

Comment: Some more posts at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5ddetect%20touchscreen See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer